# Easy way to set Maven repository on home Tomcat

Tags: maven

I have created a test artifact. Maven finds it on the local machine. Now I want to publish it on my home site. May anyone advice on it or on documentation.

I tried the manual way but failed to find good description of things like .pom files. The maven-automated way is not very clear documented either. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you created the artifact? using maven itself? what exactly are you trying to publish and where? please elaborate!

Comment: I created a standard sample hello-maven-plugin and run mvn install. I created the sample my-project-usage as well in a far away folder on my computer and run mvn install there - OK, I see "[INFO] Hello, world" in the console. 
Now I want to put it on my home server so I created Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\maven2\sample\plugin\hello-maven-plugin\1.0-SNAPSHOT and put the jar file there. I try to run the my-project-usage on my another home computer (added  <pluginRepository> with URL). It looks like it finds the jar over http but that jar is not sufficient, talks about .pom and more.

Comment: I was advised on NEXUS etc but it seems a too complex solution for just-one-time need.

Comment: C:\my-project-usage>cmd /k mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Building my-project-usage 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Downloading: .../maven2/sample/plugin/hello-maven-plugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: .../maven2/sample/plugin/hello-maven-plugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello-maven-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
...

Comment: Note - it is really looking for .pom - is it same as .pom.xml?

Comment: Here is the link I try to follow: http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That turned out being very simple - I copied folder "sample" from C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\ to ...\Tomcat7.0\webapps\ROOT\maven2\ and was able to run the test build on another computer via http. Apparently there may be same simple but more elegant ways.